# how to insert data into database in electron SQl as database And React as front end

Tags: node.js, electron

I am new at Electron.

I am trying to build a small app using Electron. What I am trying to do is to insert the data which is taken from front end.

I am using SQL has database and react as front end can any give suggestions.

How to insert data? 
Can any one please give me the solution for it?

Please help me.

I tried like this: this is my Index .html and I need to post the data which is taken from here. And in ZIpcode.js MySQL code will be there.

### Index.html

```
<div>
                    <form className =" col-lg-12 form-horizontal" role="form" >
                        <nav className="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
                            <div className = "container-fluid">
                                <div className="navbar-header">
                                    <div className="col-lg-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                                        <div className ="row">
                                            <div className="col-lg-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2">
                                                <button type="submit" id="btnSubmit" className="btn btn-primary center-block">
                                                    Submit
                                                </button>
                                            </div>
                                            <div className="col-lg-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-1">
                                                <button type="reset" className="btn btn-danger center-block">
                                                    Cancel
                                                </button>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </nav>
                        <br/><br/><br/>
                        <div className ="container">
                            <div className = "row">
                                <div className = "row">
                                    <div className="col-lg-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                                        <div className="form-group">
                                            <div className="col-lg-1 col-sm-1">
                                            </div>
                                            <label className="control-label col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12" for="ZipCode">Zip Code:</label>
                                            <div className="col-lg-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                                                <input type="number" className="form-control" id="ZipCode" ref = "ZipCode" placeholder="Zip Code" required="true"/>
                                            </div>
                                            <div className="col-lg-1 col-sm-1">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div className="col-lg-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                                        <div className="form-group">
                                            <label className="control-label col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12" for="ShortCode">Short Code:</label>
                                            <div className="col-lg-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                                                <input type="Short Code" className="form-control" id="ShortCode" ref = "ShortCode" placeholder="Short Code" required="true"/>
                                            </div>
                                            <div className="col-lg-2 col-sm-2">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div  className = "row">
                                    <div className="col-lg-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                                        <div className="form-group">
                                            <div className="col-lg-1 col-sm-1">
                                            </div>
                                            <label className="control-label col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12" for="City">City:</label>
                                            <div className="col-lg-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                                                <input type="City" className="form-control" id="City" ref = "City" placeholder="City" required="true"/>
                                            </div>
                                            <div className="col-lg-1 col-sm-1">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div className="col-lg-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                                        <div className="form-group">
                                            <label className="control-label col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12" for="State">State:</label>
                                            <div className="col-lg-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                                                <input type="State" className="form-control" id="State" ref = "State" placeholder="State" required="true"/>
                                            </div>
                                            <div className="col-lg-2 col-sm-2">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div className = "row">
                                    <div className="col-lg-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                                        <div className="form-group">
                                            <div className="col-lg-1 col-sm-1">
                                            </div>
                                            <label className="control-label col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12" for="PhoneAreaCode">Phone Area Code:</label>
                                            <div className="col-lg-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                                                <input type="PhoneAreaCode" className="form-control" id="PhoneAreaCode" ref = "PhoneAreaCode" placeholder="Phone Area Code" required="true"/>
                                            </div>
                                            <div className="col-lg-1 col-sm-1">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div className="col-lg-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div className = "row">
                                    <div className="col-lg-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                                        <div className="form-group">
                                            <div className="col-lg-1 col-sm-1">
                                            </div>
                                            <label className="control-label col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12" for="TaxCode">Tax Code:</label>
                                            <div className="col-lg-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                                                <input type="TaxCode" className="form-control" id="TaxCode" ref = "TaxCode" placeholder="Tax Code" required="true"/>
                                            </div>
                                            <div className="col-lg-1 col-sm-1">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div className="col-lg-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                                        <div className="form-group">
                                            <label className="control-label col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12" for="Tax">%Tax:</label>
                                            <div className="col-lg-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                                                <input type="number" className="form-control" id="Tax" ref = "Tax" placeholder="Tax" required="true"/>
                                            </div>
                                            <div className="col-lg-2 col-sm-2">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
```

### zipcode.js

```
window.onload = function() {

document.getElementById("btnSubmit").onclick = function () {
    alert('Submit button click');
    var v1 = document.getElementById('ZipCode').value;
    var v2 = document.getElementById('ShortCode').value;
    var v3 = document.getElementById('City').value;
    var v4 = document.getElementById('State').value;
    var v5 = document.getElementById('PhoneAreaCode').value;
    var v6 = document.getElementById('TaxCode').value;
    var v7 = document.getElementById('Tax').value;
    //alert("ZipCode:"+v1+" "+"ShortCode:"+v2+" "+"City:"+v3)
    //sql connection
    //alert('after Connection');
    var Connection = require('tedious').Connection;

    var config = {
        userName: 'xx',
        password: 'xxxx',
        server: 'xxxxxx', // You can use 'localhost\\instance' to connect to named instance
        database: 'XXXXX',
        options: {
            database: 'XXXXX'
        },
    }
    alert("SQL")
    var connection = new Connection(config);
    connection.on('connect',function(err){
        alert('hai')
        if(err){
            console.log(err)
        }
        executeStatement();
    });
    Request = require('tedious').Request;
    function executeStatement(){
        //alert(v1,v2,v3,v4,v5,v6,v7)
        var request = new Request("INSERT INTO XXXXX VALUES ("+v1+",'"+v2+"','"+v3+"','"+v4+"','"+v5+"','"+v6+"',"+v7+")",
            function(err,result){
                console.log(request)
                if(err){
                    console.log(err);
                }else{
                    console.log(result)
                }
            });
        connection.execSql(request);
    }
    alert('completion')
  }
}
```

Comment: Share with us what have you tried already.

Comment: above is my my code but it not working correctly can you please give me the solution for it

Comment: Can you be more specific? Do you get an exception? Does the data pass successfully from server to client side? What line causes the error when you debug server / client side code?

Comment: i am trying to insert it from client side i.e from react i am trying to post the data into database not for retrieving the data from database,in electron i want to know where did i need to write the service for post?

Comment: I am using react.js as front end it was there in the above above what happening here is that it store data correctly but where i am confused is that when i remove the alert messages in my index.js it not comming to the connection.on can you check it give me the solution thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Tedious is a package that connects using the TDS protocol and AFIAK it does not support MySQL.

If you are using MySQL, perhaps you should try [Sequelize js](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/) or [node-mysql](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql/).

**Update:** Based on your comment, it sounds like you need to change the order in which things execute. You can do this by moving the dependent code (the code to execute after connection) to the end of your connection callback function like this...

```
var connection = new Connection(config);
connection.on('connect',function(err){
    alert('hai')
    if(err){
        console.log(err)
    }
    else{
      Request = require('tedious').Request;
      function executeStatement(){
          //alert(v1,v2,v3,v4,v5,v6,v7)
          var request = new Request("INSERT INTO XXXXX VALUES ("+v1+",'"+v2+"','"+v3+"','"+v4+"','"+v5+"','"+v6+"',"+v7+")",
              function(err,result){
                  console.log(request)
                  if(err){
                      console.log(err);
                  }else{
                      console.log(result)
                  }
              });
          connection.execSql(request);
      }
    }
    alert('completion')
});
```

Also, you may have missed a semicolon, and have an extra comma...

```
var config = {
    userName: 'xx',
    password: 'xxxx',
    server: 'xxxxxx', // You can use 'localhost\\instance' to connect to named instance
    database: 'XXXXX',
    options: {
        database: 'XXXXX'
    }  // <-- no comma here
};    // <-- add semicolon here
```

Comment: Then please say more about the errors you are getting. See Jan's comment.

Comment: what happening in my code is that, when i click on submit button then zipcode.js file will be executed,it correctly working up to the alert('SQL') line after that it directly go to the alert('complete') line,i need wait that line until  connection.on('connect',function(err){ function executed executed.For that i am using promises but not working.Can anyone give me the best solution for it                                                                                                                Thanks,

Comment: I tried like that also but it not working what happened here is that it not coming to the connection.on function

Comment: It looks like your var config needs a semicolon, and there is an extra coma after the options object inside the config object. Please check your original code.

Comment: yah i checked my code it not worked i changed it,But it working like as before.It not coming to the connection.on function

Comment: I just kept the alert messages to know that whether it coming to that line or not, for checking purpose i put that alert messages.

Comment: I understand. If you see both the alert "SQL" AND the alert "hai", you should add more alerts inside of the connect.on() to find exactly where function is failing.

Comment: yah i tried  it, it is not coming to after connection.on (i.e) after this line var connection = new Connection(config);

Comment: is there any possibility to create  API's in electron

Comment: Then you need to debug your Tedious connection by enabling debuging in  options.debug, and catching the events. Here is a reference:  http://pekim.github.io/tedious/api-connection.html#function_newConnection

Yes you can create an API in electron. It's basically the same as creating an API in Node.js.

Comment: Then can i use node modules here like express,what happening here is that when i install express,electron is not working,can you please provide some sample for post  from front-end in electron.please help me

Comment: Your question was about getting SQL working with Electron. If you have a different question you should ask it in another post.